# How can I parse a yaml-config out of a db-table with Activerecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a table in my db which saves a config as a yaml-file. 
The respective column is called `config`.

I would like to read, let's say, the first 5 config entries, and convert them back to yaml.

I tried in the rails console, as follows:

`Person.pluck(:config).first(5).each do {|c| c.to_yaml}`

This seems to be quite wrong, I know. The first thing that got me tripping:

- Why will `Person.first(5).pluck(:config)` yield a NoMethodError?
- Doing it the way I do it above will first pluck ALL configs and then retrieve the first 5 rows, correct? How can I speed up the query?

Second question:

- What would be the correct way, to iterate over the returned table rows (e.g. the first 5), and convert the content of each config-column back to yaml via the `to_yaml`-method?

Comment: Use `YAML.parse c` if you are parsing a YAML string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why will Person.first(5).pluck(:config) yield a NoMethodError?

It yields a `NoMethodError` because you are trying to send the message `pluck` to an Array, which has no such method.

> Doing it the way I do it above will first pluck ALL configs and then retrieve the first 5 rows, correct? How can I speed up the query?

Yes, that is correct. If you want to pluck the config out of just the first five records, use `limit`:

```
Person.limit(5).pluck(:config)
```

For info on how to parse the `config` values as YAML, see [this thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/207363).

Comment: Thx!
Strangely, when I try to runs this in irb I get:

`Person.limit(5).pluck(:config).each do { |c| c.to_yaml }`

                                         ^
`(irb):61: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end`

Comment: Sorry there should be no `do` in there, I fixed my answer.